# How to change text with a function with a .cshtml file?

Tags: asp.net, razor

So, I am extremely new to using Razor and ASP, but I am trying to have a function within a button that changes the text when clicked.  With the code I have below, I am **getting**: `Method must have a return type.`

I would like the original button to **say**: `Change the Text!" and on click the button to say "Hello!`

```
@{ 
    var text = "Change the Text!";
}


@functions{
    onclick()
    { 
     var text = "Hello!";
    }
}

<button onclick="changeText()">@text</button>
```

I have looked up this problem online but I would just like to know how to properly execute this function?

Comment: Onclick expects a JavaScript event handler, so you are trying to invoke a C# server side function using JavaScript

Answer (score 0):

I think you are mixing Javascript and Razor.  Razor is a templating engine which will only render Any Javascript, HTML, and Css.....

Anything goes inside  @ {}   block will be c# .
so any methods should have a return type as C# enforces it.

Corrrect way should be as following.

```
@functions{
 string   onclick()
    { 
     var text = "Hello!";
    }
}
```

Yet this will not help your requirement.